# Bash: How do I read a plist value into a variable?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

Using bash (on BSD Unix, mac):

```
#This successfully returns the plist value (YES or NO):
defaults read com.apple.finder.plist AppleShowAllFiles
#This does not work:
myVar=default read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles
echo $myVar
```

What I am driving at, eventually, is testing the value of AppleShowFiles in a bash script, like so:

```
if[myVar="YES"]
then
#code block
else
#code block
fi
```

By the way, I am not sure about the quotation marks…
What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just do this: ```myVar=$(defaults read com.apple.finder.plist AppleShowAllFiles)```.

Comment: Efficient. If you delete your comment and re-post it as an answer, I shall up-vote you!

Comment: @BriceCoustillas, no worries. Just upvote the already posted answer pointed by 0stone0.